# How to set object property Value reference from another object property value in an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reference-type

I have a list of task which contains [Start Date] and [Finish Date]. At some point I assign `Tasks[1].StartDate = Tasks[0].FinishDate` So when I change the Finish Date of task at index 0 the start date of task at index 1 should also change. But some reason it is not working and it is not reference type.

```
task.startDate = vm.tasks[idx].finishDate;
task.finishDate = moment(task.startDate).add('days', task.days);
```

I have a days property on the object which changes the finishDate when it is changed.

How the startDate can be referenced when its value is assigned from another object property

Comment: try angular.copy().

Comment: You are breaking the reference when you re-assign a new object value to `task.finishDate`. But also depends on whether you have date string or date object as value. Not 100% clear what expectations are. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: 'task.finishDate' is not referenced 'task.startDate' is referenced with another objects' 'finishDate'. Originally it is Json Date but I am using moment.js to calculate date and assign date object.

Comment: Not at all clear what is expected here. Need a better explanation and [mcve]